# Code to add a sheet and rename that sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Code to add a sheet and rename that sheet from the user.

```
Sub tenloops1()
    
    Worksheets.Add
    
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: My code is not working. I was not able to rename the added sheet with the name user provides

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Name = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")` and make sure the user does not enter any invalid characters.

Comment: Posted a late answer demonstrating some new methodical aspects in validity checks :-) @SathishThirunavukkarasu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to VBA and hope the code does what you want.

```
Sub tenloops1()

Worksheets.Add

ActiveSheet.Name = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")

End Sub
```

Comment: It Worked. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I would do this slightly different to minimize the error that can happen when you are adding and naming a sheet.

**Logic**

You have to take care of the following

1. The sheet name is valid. i.e It is not an empty string or it is not more than 31 characters. Neither it should contain the characters `/,\,[,],*,?,:`
2. There should not be a sheet already with that name.
3. Error Handling `On Error GoTo...` to catch any other errors that may rise.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Variant
    
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    '~~> Get user input
    Ret = InputBox("Enter a valid sheet name")
    
    If Ret = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    '~~> Check if the sheet name is valid
    If IsValidSheetName(Ret) = False Then
        MsgBox "The sheet name cannot have length more than 31 " & _
               "characters. Neither it can contain the characters /,\,[,],*,?,:"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '~~> Check if there is no other sheet with that name
    If DoesSheetExist(Ret) Then
        MsgBox "There is already a sheet with that name. Enter a new name"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    '~~> Add the sheet and name it in one go
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = Ret
    
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

Private Function IsValidSheetName(userinput As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim IllegalChars As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    IllegalChars = Array("/", "\", "[", "]", "*", "?", ":")
    
    If Len(userinput) > 31 Then Exit Function
    
    For i = LBound(IllegalChars) To UBound(IllegalChars)
        If InStr(userinput, (IllegalChars(i))) > 0 Then Exit Function
    Next i

    IsValidSheetName = True
End Function

Private Function DoesSheetExist(userinput As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(userinput)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not wsh Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExist = True
End Function
```

Comment: Helpful indeed and well explained +:) -  fyi you might be interested in my partially alternative check methods  @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 2):

```
ActiveSheet.Name = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")
```

and make sure the user does not enter any invalid characters.

You can also do it this way:

```
Sub tenloops1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sName as String
    sName = InputBox("Enter Sheet Name")

    ' also may want to check for sName being a valid sheet name here
    If Len(sName) > 0 Then 
      Set ws = Worksheets.Add()
      ws.Name = sName
    Else
      ' user clicked cancel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great Code. Thank you.

Comment: Please select one of the answers as accepted using the green checkmark on the upper left so the question does not remain open.

Answer (score 2):

**Structured example call**

- `[1]` Get user input
- `[2]` Repeat in a loop if a sheet name is invalid or exists already
- `[3]` Add sheet and name it

This approach doesn't pretend to be the best one, but you can profit from studying it, as it demonstrates an alternative approach in help functions `b)` and `c)`

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '[1] Get user input
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Dim Sheetname As String
    Sheetname = InputBox("Enter a valid sheet name or leave blank to exit.")
    If Sheetname = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '[2] Check sheet validity (via help function SheetError()
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Do While SheetError(Sheetname, ThisWorkbook)
        If Sheetname = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        Sheetname = InputBox("Enter a valid sheet name")
        If StrPtr(Sheetname) = 0 Then MsgBox "Cancelled by user.": Exit Sub
    Loop
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '[3] Add sheet and name it
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = Sheetname
End Sub
```

**Function `SheetError()`**

Controls user inputs of sheet names in ExampleCall and uses two help functions `b)` and `c)`

```
Private Function SheetError(Sheetname As String, wb As Workbook, Optional ShowMsg As Boolean = True) As Boolean
'Purpose: check for possible sheet errors; return True if so

    Dim msg As String
    'a) Check sheet length
    If Not Len(Sheetname) Or Len(Sheetname) > 31 Then
        If ShowMsg Then msg = "The sheet name cannot be empty or have more than 31 characters." & vbNewLine
        SheetError = True
    End If
    'b) Check if sheet already exists
        If SheetExists(Sheetname, wb) Then
            If ShowMsg Then msg = msg & "There is already a sheet with that name. Enter a new name!" & vbNewLine
            SheetError = True
        End If
    'c) Check if the sheet name is valid
    If IsValidSheetName(Sheetname) = False Then
        If ShowMsg Then msg = msg & "The sheet name must not contain /,\,[,],*,?,: characters."
        SheetError = True
    End If
    If SheetError And ShowMsg Then MsgBox msg, vbExclamation, "Sheet Error"
End Function
```

---

**Help function b) `SheetExists()`**

Allows a one line check:

```
Private Function SheetExists(Sheetname As String, wb As Workbook) As Boolean
'Purp.: check if sheet exists
'Date:  2021-03-08
'Auth.: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
    SheetExists = Not IsError(Application.Evaluate("'" & wb.Path & "\[" & wb.Name & "]" & Sheetname & "'!A1"))
End Function
```

**Help function c) `IsValidSheetName()`**

Compares a **byte array (`by`)** derived from sheetname characters with an **array of illegal characters (`illegalAsc`)** via `Application.Match()`.

Note that

- Match() isn't restricted to only 1 array argument!
  (shows the 1-based positions of illegal occurrencies, non-findings error)
- Count() ignores error elements, so it suffices to detect at least one occurrence of an element

The illegal characters not allowed in sheet names are `/\[]*?:`

```
Private Function IsValidSheetName(Sheetname As String) As Boolean
'Auth.: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
'Purp.: check for valid sheet name
'Date:   2021-03-08
    '0) don't allow empty sheetname //edited due to comment
    If Sheetname = vbNullString Then Exit Function

    'a) length cannot exceed 31 characters
    If Len(Sheetname) > 31 Then Exit Function
    'b) define illegal character codes
    Dim IllegalAsc As Variant
    IllegalAsc = Array(47, 92, 91, 93, 42, 63, 58)  ' i.e. /\[]*?:
    'c) convert name to byte array
    Dim by() As Byte: by = Sheetname
    'd) return true if no counted occurrencies of illegal matches
    With Application
        IsValidSheetName = .Count(.Match(IllegalAsc, by, 0)) = 0   ' edited due to comment
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: ++ Nicely Done :)

Comment: Great. The `IsValidSheetName` procedure is a brilliant idea, but I'm wondering about three details. Why is `SheetName` declared as `Variant`? Also, I wouldn't want it to go beyond the first line if `SheetName` were an empty string (...`And Len(SheetName) < 1`...). Couldn't it be 'simplified' with `IsValidSheetName = .Count(.Match(IllegalAsc, by, 0)) = 0` (maybe in parentheses after the first equal sign)?

Comment: Once again I appreciate your valuable & simplifying input @VBasic2008 - edited 1st and 3rd proposal :-) As for the 2nd proposal: Of course it would make sense to integrate this to test validity in a general function. In this case, however I preferred to isolate it from error messages and catch it already in the calling code (loop in section `[2]`) .