# Copy a sheet and clear contents in the same time

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this function for clearing contents

```
Sub ClearData()

Range("K2,J3,B18:B38,H18:H38,I18:I38,J18:J38,F44").Value = ""

End Sub
```

And this other function to copy the last sheet with the same content and also give it a name

```
Public Sub CopySheetAndRename()
  Dim newName As String

  On Error Resume Next
  newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")

  If newName <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = newName
  End If
  
End Sub
```

But what I need is that when I press the button to create the new copied sheet I also what to clear some cells in the new sheet. Now I have two buttons and I want only one button that must do what the other 2 are doing.

I am new at this and still learning.

I tried to combine the code but with no luck.

Thank you all for the help. Now if someone knows how to get rid of the next text box every time I make a new sheet, please tell.

[image]

Comment: If you just want to have ClearData to go off when you use CopySheetAndRename. Use `End If
ClearData
End Sub`

and in ClearData you can use `.ClearContents` instead of `.Value = ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Duplicate a Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DuplicateWorksheet()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Duplicate Worksheet"
    Const IB_PROMPT As String = "Enter the name for the duplicate worksheet"
    Const CLEAR_RANGE As String = "K2,J3,B18:B38,H18:H38,I18:I38,J18:J38,F44"
    
    ' Input the destination worksheet name.
    Dim NewName As String: NewName = InputBox(IB_PROMPT, PROC_TITLE)
    
    ' Check if no entry or the dialog was canceled.
    If Len(NewName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No name entered.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet and the workbook.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = sws.Parent
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Copy the source and reference this copy, the destination worksheet.
    sws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' after last sheet
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' last sheet
    
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    
    ' Attempt to rename the destination worksheet.
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent several possible errors
        dws.Name = NewName
        ErrNum = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Check if the rename was successful.
    If ErrNum <> 0 Then ' could not rename
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            dws.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MsgBox "Could not rename to '" & NewName & "'.", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    'Else ' could rename; do nothing (continue)
    End If
    
    ' Clear.
    dws.Range(CLEAR_RANGE).ClearContents
               
    ' Save!?
    'wb.Save
               
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "The name of the duplicated worksheet is '" & NewName & "'.", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had to change the ' Clear.
    dws.Range(CLEAR_RANGE).ClearContents TO ' Clear.
    dws.Range(CLEAR_RANGE).Value = "" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the other macro from a macro. In your `CopySheetAndRename` macro, if you write `Call ClearData` or even just `ClearData` (since VBA can figure out the `Call` part by itself), VBA will run `ClearData` inside your `CopySheetAndRename` macro.

```vb
Public Sub CopySheetAndRename()
  Dim newName As String

  On Error Resume Next
  newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")

  If newName <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = newName
    ClearData
  End If
  
End Sub
```

My advice for your code would be to not use `ActiveSheet`. As your code gets more complicated, especially when you're creating or changing sheets mid-execution, `ActiveSheet` will be hard to keep track of, and may end up causing problems for you. In my experience, something ends up running on the wrong sheet and damaging all the data.

Add a `Worksheet` argument to `ClearData` so that you can be sure you're not running it on the wrong sheet. And save the new sheet as a variable as soon as possible, before anything else changes `ActiveSheet`.

```vb
Sub ClearData(Target As Worksheet)
  Target.Range("K2,J3,B18:B38,H18:H38,I18:I38,J18:J38,F44").Value = ""
End Sub
Public Sub CopySheetAndRename()
  Dim newName As String

  On Error Resume Next
  newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")

  If newName <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.Name = newName
    ClearData ws
  End If
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Might also be worth putting in a `CheckName` function - no longer than 31, not "History", doesn't contain the characters ``~!@#$%^&()-_=+{}|;:,<.>` and sheet with that name doesn't already exist.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook: How did you come up with this characters list? Only 8 are mentioned in the error message. Are the additional ones based on (your) best practice or is there more to it?

Comment: That's a wide scope for `On Error Resume Next`. And why are there two instances without a 'closing' `On Error Goto 0`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 I didn't want to edit Alex's code too much, I just wanted to show an example of how to implement my solution and suggestions in their code. I think this makes it easier for the question asker to understand the solution.

Comment: Side note to @DarrenBartrup-Cook : possible `CheckName` function at [Add sheet ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522924/code-to-add-a-sheet-and-rename-that-sheet/66536054#66536054)

Comment: Thank you for the help, it works. And also for the advice.

Comment: @VBasic2008. I think I got the list from [here](https://www.keynotesupport.com/excel-basics/worksheet-names-characters-allowed-prohibited.shtml).  I admit I didn't check it, but it looked about right so went with it.  Just checked on the [MS website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-a-worksheet-3f1f7148-ee83-404d-8ef0-9ff99fbad1f9#:~:text=Important%3A%C2%A0Worksheet%20names%20cannot%3A%201%20Be%20blank%20.%202,This%20is%20a%20reserved%20word%20Excel%20uses%20internally.) where it says `/ \ ? * : [ ]`.  Looks like my list was wrong - definitely accepts `~` and `!` as names.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The list is of some importance though. On the web page the following is stated: *"The following character symbols are allowed, but if the worksheet name contains a blank or any of these characters, the name must be wrapped in single quotes when manually entering formulas to link worksheet data. The apostrophe ( ' ) cannot be used at the beginning or end of a worksheet name, but can be used in the middle of a name."*.