# rename sheet through ms access vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've tried multiple ways to get this to work.

And just keep getting "Method 'Name' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

The function "Worksheetexists" returns a Boolean.

I can't narrow down the issue...

```
Dim xlappC As Excel.Application
Dim xlbookC As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsheetC As Excel.Worksheet
Dim fpath As String
Dim n As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim scacVar As String
Dim temp As String

'set file path for Kichler Master file
fpath = "pathname"

'open the excel workbook
Set xlappC = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlbookC = xlappC.Workbooks.Open(fpath)
Set xlsheetC = xlbookC.Worksheets("Carrier Pay - Tab to Delete")
With xlappC
    'activate the Carrier Pay sheet
    xlsheetC.Activate
    'n = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    n = 5
    'loop through all the data that is pasted on the Carrier Pay sheet
    For i = 2 To n
        scacVar = Range("E" & i).Value2
        temp = WorksheetExists(scacVar, xlbookC)
        If temp = False Then
            Set xlsheetC = xlbookC.Worksheets("Sheet4")
            xlsheetC.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            'xlsheetC.Name = scacVar
            Set xlsheetC = xlbookC.Worksheets("Sheet4 (2)")
            'xlsheetC.Activate
            'ActiveSheet.Name = scacVar
            'xlsheetC.Name = scacVar
            'With xlsheetC
                '.Name = scacVar
            'End With
        End If
    Next i
    xlbookC.Close SaveChanges:=True
End With
```

Comment: Either `scacVar` is too long or empty or contains invalid characters. What value does `scacVar` have when this fails? In other words, what does `Debug.Print scacVar` return to the Immediate Window?

Comment: just tested and it is returning a string of 4 characters as expected. all letters

Comment: How exactly did you test this?

Comment: Which line triggers error? Did you step debug?

Comment: @BigBen using msgbox to return scacVar

Comment: @June7 I've commented all the lines, but any point that I tried ".Name" is where the error occurs.

Comment: What happens if you try `xlSheetC.Name = "Name"`, where you replace `Name` with the hard-coded value of the variable `scacVar`? It should at least succeed on the first iteration.

Comment: @BigBen it behaves as it should. new sheet with the name "name." back to the debugging drawing board. want to figure this

Comment: Your problem is likely to implicit Worksheet references. Also reusing `xlsheetC` seems a bit problematic.

Comment: @BigBen agreed. just tested by changing i = 5 and it creates a new copy of sheet4 and renames it with the 4 letter code as intended. will continue my process. ty for pointing in the right direction

Comment: @BigBen wow. i = 2 works. however, this moves this activesheet to the new sheet. i = 3 is then returning a null value as there is nothing on that sheet. thanks again

Comment: You have temp declared as a String yet you test for a Boolean value. Doubt pertinent to issue but why not declare as Boolean?

Comment: @June7 I realize now that I probably can just move the function to be part of the IF statement instead of loading it into a variable.

Comment: I tested your code and  first iteration to name new sheet works. It's the next iteration that fails, most likely because of hard-coded references to Sheet4 and code is adding sheets to workbook. Step debugging shows that scacVar variable is empty on second iteration. Hopefully one of the two answers provided addresses this.

Answer (score 3):

a) you should tell the VBA engine exactly on which object you want to work. For example, to read the cell content, use

```
scacVar = xlsheetC.Range("E" & i).Value2
```

and for copying the sheet, use

```
xlsheetC.Copy After:=xlbookC.Sheets(xlbookC.Sheets.Count)
```

b) Although it works, I would suggest not to assume that the copied sheet gets the exact name `Sheet4 (2)`. The copied sheet will always be the Active Sheet, so use

```
Set newSheet = xlappC.ActiveSheet
```

Note that The Access VBA environment does not know anything about ActiveSheet, so you should specify that this is a member of the Excel Application object.

c) The correct way to set the name of the sheet is `newSheet.Name = ...`. However, you get the error message when the name you want to assign is invalid (eg empty). Check the content of `scacVar` with the debugger in case the error occurs

**Update** As BigBen pointed out, you should use a new variable to assign the newly created sheet because you want `xlsheetC` to point to the carrier sheet. I named it `newSheet`.

Comment: *ad* **c)** user @Dennis might want to check the content/validity of `scacVar` also programmatically via function `IsValidSheetName()` proposed in [code to add a sheet ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66522924/code-to-add-a-sheet-and-rename-that-sheet/66536054#66536054)

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding `Activate` and implicit Workbook/Worksheet references should likely solve your problem. Also, "reusing" `xlsheetC` should be avoided ... you want a reference to that `Worksheet` for the entire iteration.

```
For i = 2 to n
     scacVar = xlsheetC.Range("E" & i).Value2

     If Not WorksheetExists(scacVar, xlbookC) Then
          With xlbookC
              .Worksheets("Sheet4").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)

              .Sheets(.Sheets.Count).Name = scacVar
          End With
     End If
Next
```

In other words, this is problematic:

```
scacVar = Range("E" & i).Value2
```

It's implicitly:

```
scacVar = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value2
```

but the `ActiveSheet` changes when you copy a Worksheet!

Comment: much cleaner version than what I was doing. Still find that I need to do xlsheetC.Activate to get it to go back to "Carrier Pay - Tab to Delete" sheet

Comment: You don't need to activate that sheet to get a value from one of its cells though. If you want to activate it after looping, then sure. Highly suggest reading [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), which also applies to `Activate`.

Comment: because instead of telling it pick cells from "THIS" sheet specifically it's just using the active sheet. I'll rework to be more explicit as you suggested in comments. thank you

Comment: But nothing in the proposed solution is using the active sheet.

Comment: Ah. I missed where the scacVar code was changed.

Answer (score 2):

### Access: Create Excel Worksheets From Template

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**The Code**

- I successfully ran the code in `Access`, `Excel`, `PowerPoint`, `Publisher`, and `Word`.
- The code uses early binding i.e. it requires a reference to the *Microsoft Excel Object Library* to be created (not in Excel, of course). Use `VBE --> Tools --> References`.

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates and renames copies of a (template) worksheet
'               using a list (column) in another worksheet.
' Flow:         It launches a new instance of Excel, opens the workbook,
'               applies the changes, and saves and closes the workbook
'               before closing the instance.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub CreateWorksheetsFromTemplate()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Create Worksheets From Template"
    Const DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS As Boolean = True
    Dim WasSuccess As Boolean
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Set the file path for the Kichler Master file.
    Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Test\Test.xlsx"
    Const SRC_TEMPLATE As String = "Sheet4"
    Const SRC_LIST As String = "Carrier Pay - Tab to Delete"
    Const SRC_FIRST_LIST_CELL As String = "E2"
        
    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
        Debug.Print "Running """ & PROC_TITLE & """."
    End If
    
    ' Check if the file exists.
    If Len(Dir(FILE_PATH)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & FILE_PATH & """ doesn't exist!", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
        Debug.Print "Found the file """ & FILE_PATH; """."
    End If
    
    ' Create a reference to a newly launched instance of Excel (early binding).
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application: Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    'xlApp.Visible = True ' default is 'False'
    
    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
        Debug.Print "New instance of Excel created."
    End If
    
    ' Open and create a reference to the workbook.
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook: Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FILE_PATH)
    
    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
        Debug.Print "Workbook """ & wb.Name & """ opened."
    End If
    
    ' Create references to the worksheets
    Dim wsTemp As Excel.Worksheet: Set wsTemp = wb.Worksheets(SRC_TEMPLATE)
    Dim wsList As Excel.Worksheet: Set wsList = wb.Worksheets(SRC_LIST)
    
    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
        Debug.Print "References to worksheets """ & wsTemp.Name & """ and """ _
            & wsList.Name & """ created."
    End If
    
    ' Create a reference to the range containing the list.
    Dim rgList As Excel.Range:
    Set rgList = RefColumnRangeEnd(wsList.Range(SRC_FIRST_LIST_CELL))
    
    ' Check if the list is empty.
    If rgList Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The list is empty.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
        Debug.Print "Found the list in """ & rgList.Address(0, 0) & """."
    End If
    
    ' Return the list in an array.
    Dim Data(): Data = GetRangeColumn(rgList)
    
    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
        On Error Resume Next
            Debug.Print "Returned the following list in the array:" _
                & vbLf & Join(xlApp.Transpose(Data), vbLf)
        On Error GoTo ClearError
    End If
    
    ' Declare new variables used in the upcoming loop.
    Dim SheetName As Variant, r As Long, ErrNumber As Long, Msg As String
    Dim IsCopyAvailable As Boolean
    
    ' For each sheet name in the array, copy the template worksheet
    ' as the last sheet and rename it.
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        SheetName = Data(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(SheetName) Then ' the corresponding cell has no error
            If Len(SheetName) > 0 Then ' the corresponding cell is not blank
                If IsSheetNameAvailable(wb, SheetName) Then ' sheet doesn't exist
                    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
                        Debug.Print r & ".) Processing name """ & SheetName _
                            & """:"
                    End If
                    If Not IsCopyAvailable Then ' no copy available
                        wsTemp.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
                        IsCopyAvailable = True
                        If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
                            Debug.Print "    Template copied."
                        End If
                    Else ' a copy is available; do nothing
                        If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
                            Debug.Print "    Template not copied; " _
                                & "a copy is already available!"
                        End If
                    End If
                    If RenameSheet(wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count), SheetName) Then
                        If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
                            Debug.Print "    Created """ & SheetName & """."
                        End If
                        IsCopyAvailable = False
                    Else ' could not be renamed; do nothing
                        If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
                            Debug.Print "    Not created the invalid """ _
                                & SheetName & """!"
                        End If
                    End If
                Else ' sheet exists (sheet name is not available); do nothing
                    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
                        Debug.Print r & ".) A sheet named """ & SheetName _
                            & """" & " already exists."
                    End If
                End If
            Else ' the corresponding cell is blank; do nothing
                If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
                    Debug.Print r & ".) The corresponding cell is blank!"
                End If
            End If
        Else ' the corresponding cell has an error; do nothing
            If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
                Debug.Print r & ".) The corresponding cell has an error!"
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Delete excessive worksheet and close saving changes.
    
    If IsCopyAvailable Then ' there is an extra worksheet; delete it
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
             wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Delete
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
        If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
            Debug.Print "Deleting excessive worksheet!"
        End If
    'Else ' there is no extra worksheet; do nothing
    End If
    
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
        Debug.Print "Workbook saved and closed."
    End If
    
    WasSuccess = True
    
    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
        Debug.Print "The code ran successfully."
    End If

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        ' Close the workbook.
        If Not WasSuccess Then
            If Not wb Is Nothing Then
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
                If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
                    Debug.Print "Workbook not saved but closed!"
                End If
            End If
        End If
        ' Close the instance.
        If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then
            xlApp.Quit
            If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
                Debug.Print "Quitting Excel."
            End If
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If WasSuccess Then
        MsgBox "Worksheets successfully created.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    If DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS Then
        Debug.Print "An error occurred!"
    End If
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**The Help - Reference a Single-Column Range**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the single-column range between a given
'               cell ('firstCell') and the bottom-most visible occupied cell.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumnRangeEnd( _
    ByVal firstCell As Excel.Range) _
As Excel.Range

    If firstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim rg As Excel.Range
    
    With firstCell
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Worksheet _
            .Cells(.Worksheet.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRow < .Row Then Exit Function
        Set rg = .Resize(LastRow - .Row + 1, 1)
    End With
    
    Set RefColumnRangeEnd = rg

End Function
```

**The Help - Get Range Column**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the data from an Excel range's column ('ColumnNumber')
'               in a 2D one-based single-column array.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRangeColumn( _
    ByVal rg As Excel.Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber < 0 Then Exit Function
    If rg.Columns.Count < ColumnNumber Then Exit Function
    
    Dim Data() As Variant
    
    If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
    Else
        Data = rg.Value
    End If
    
    GetRangeColumn = Data

End Function
```

**The Help - Is Sheet Name Available**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether an Excel workbook ('wb')
'               doesn't contain a sheet with the specified name ('SheetName').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function IsSheetNameAvailable( _
    ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook, _
    ByVal SheetName As String) _
As Boolean
    
    Dim sh As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sh = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    IsSheetNameAvailable = sh Is Nothing

End Function
```

**The Help - Rename Sheet**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Attempts to rename an Excel sheet ('sh') with a given name
'               ('NewSheetName') and returns a boolean indicating
'               whether it was successful.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RenameSheet( _
    ByVal sh As Object, _
    ByVal NewSheetName As String) _
As Boolean
    
    Dim ErrNumber As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
        sh.Name = NewSheetName
        ErrNumber = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    RenameSheet = ErrNumber = 0

End Function
```

**The Log (`DEBUG_PRINT_PROGRESS = True`)**

```
Running "Create Worksheets From Template".
Found the file "C:\Test\Test.xlsx".
New instance of Excel created.
Workbook "Test.xlsx" opened.
References to worksheets "Sheet4" and "Carrier Pay - Tab to Delete" created.
Found the list in "E2:E11".
1.) Processing name "John":
    Template copied.
    Created "John".
2.) Processing name "Mary":
    Template copied.
    Created "Mary".
3.) The corresponding cell is blank!
4.) The corresponding cell has an error!
5.) The corresponding cell is blank!
6.) The corresponding cell has an error!
7.) Processing name "/Liam/":
    Template copied.
    Not created the invalid "/Liam/"!
8.) Processing name "Peter":
    Template not copied; a copy is already available!
    Created "Peter".
9.) Processing name "Frank":
    Template copied.
    Created "Frank".
10.) Processing name "Super*Sue":
    Template copied.
    Not created the invalid "Super*Sue"!
Deleting excessive worksheet!
Workbook saved and closed.
The code ran successfully.
Quitting Excel.
```